# findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of DraggableCore which is inside StrictMode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draggable, react-strictmode

Draggable package is causing an error in strict mode:

> Warning: `findDOMNode` is deprecated in StrictMode. `findDOMNode` was
> passed an instance of DraggableCore which is inside StrictMode.
> Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference.
> Learn more about using refs safely here:
> https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#warning-about-deprecated-finddomnode-usage

Apparently they have never fixed it https://github.com/STRML/react-draggable/issues/440, do you have any nice/elegant solution?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

According with official git repository on https://github.com/STRML/react-draggable/blob/v4.4.2/lib/DraggableCore.js#L159-L171

```js
/* If running in React Strict mode, ReactDOM.findDOMNode() is deprecated.
* Unfortunately, in order for <Draggable> to work properly, we need raw access
* to the underlying DOM node. If you want to avoid the warning, pass a `nodeRef`
* as in this example:
*/

function MyComponent() {
    const nodeRef = React.useRef(null);
    return (
        <Draggable nodeRef={nodeRef}>
            <div ref={nodeRef}>Example Target</div>
        </Draggable>
    );
}

/*
* This can be used for arbitrarily nested components, so long as the ref ends up
* pointing to the actual child DOM node and not a custom component.
*/
```

it works!

Comment: Thanks for following up on your own question, this helped me out!

Comment: This should really be the default in the Draggable docs 

Comment: worked cleanly, thanks!

Comment: Passing nodeRef to Draggable makes it not draggable anymore. i.e. it can't be dragged so it makes no sense to use it. The console warnings disappear though.